# Logcat filter by application commandline w/o tags

Tags: filter, logcat

I've been searching and never found an answer that works for me.
Specifically, I want to see logcat outputs from a specific application.

I'm not using eclipse, I'm using command line `adb logcat`.

I'm only given the apk build of the application, so I don't know any tags to use the filter by tags everyone has been talking about.  I don't think I can just go in and add tags or what not.

I saw in another page someone suggested

"Use ps/grep/cut to grab the PID, then grep for logcat entries with that PID. Here's the command I use:"

```
adb logcat | grep `adb shell ps | grep com.example.package | cut -c10-15`
```

This doesn't work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using this in windows?